# text is not allowed between the opening and closing tags for element updatepanel

Tags: asp.net

My Code is like this.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">     
  <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddpCity" runat="server" Width="226px" Height="26px" >
      <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="0" Text="Select"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator11" runat="server" 
         ErrorMessage="Please Select City "  Font-Size="Small" 
         ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="ddpCity" 
         ValidationGroup="VGPJobPost"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I receive an error with this `asp:UpdatePanel`. I do also have the `content template`.

What am I missing?

Comment: I did a copy paste of your code and it works fine. Even writing text in `content template`. I guess the error is somewhere else on the page. Can you post the `full code`?

Answer (score 0):

You may see this error message when there is nothing wrong with your markup, as in this case.

The reason is that Visual Studio is trying to help you by alerting you to problems as you type, but unfortunately it has not yet caught up with your typing.

The error message will clear after sufficient time has elapsed, or when you next build the project.